Why was this new user's answer deleted within 1-2 hours of posting by "Community" bot, and then locked?
What happened here?  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/104618/revisions  Seems a rather unwelcome reception for a new user.
Under that answer Do GPS coordinates of a fixed point in space ever change?, we now see the tag "This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details."  Did the "Community" bot just make a mistake here?
Is it similar to this situation Why did the "Community" bot decide that this answer should be deleted? , where the user's account was "destroyed"?

Sorry, obvious.  ASE is welcome to delete this question.

PS just now noticed that the content in that deleted spam answer is apparently copied directly from this answer https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/104614/34686

The link posted in the answer was spam to a wildly unrelated website, likely so the site could be crawled & get a web presence with the search engines.  That is overtly malicious behavior, and yes, that absolutely warrants (and gets) a no-warning ban on the account.

OK, silly me.  I didn't even think to click on the link.  Should've been obvious.  Thnx.  Good job, Robot!
